# Simplify body of Function after replacement

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, hold

I have come across a simple example of bizarre behaviour, i.e.:

```
Function[t, t*c] /. c -> 0
```

which outputs

```
Function[t, t 0]
```

How can I make the product "t 0" evaluate to 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll):

```
Attributes[Function]
```

> {HoldAll, Protected}

This explains the behavior you're seeing. There are many ways to handle this. One that I like is to use [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate)/[`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate):

```
expr = Function[t, t*c] /. c -> 0;

Activate @ Inactivate[Evaluate @ expr, Function]
```

> Function[t, 0]

With [`Inactivate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate), you can control which parts of expr get inactivated, i.e., you can do partial evaluations. As a silly example, suppose you have:

```
expr = Function[t, 0/0 + 1 + 2]
```

> Function[t, 0/0 + 1 + 2]

You can avoid evaluating 0/0 as follows:

```
Activate @ Inactivate[Evaluate @ expr, Function | Times | Power]
```

> Function[t, 3 + 0/0]

Answer (score 5):

While [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159846/11035) is probably better in general, here I would just use the more terse [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) :

```
expr = Function[t, t*c] /. c -> 0;

MapAt[ Evaluate, expr, 2 ]
```

> ```
> Function[t, 0]
> ```

Note that the operator form makes this particularly convenient to use:

```
Function[t, t*c] /. c -> 0 // MapAt[Evaluate, 2]
```

> ```
> Function[t, 0]
> ```