# Best way to simplify a polynomial before making it the body of a function?

Tags: functions, function-construction, hold

So, I'm dealing with iterated polynomials of a single variable—say they're anonymous functions labeled as $p_i$, i.e. `p[1]`, `p[2]`, etc., and that these have explicit definitions. I'd like to compose a list of these, collect the terms, and then make the result an anonymous function. So, one way I have of doing this, with some example polynomials, is

```
indexlist0 = {1, 3, 2};
p[1] = (#^2 + 1 &);
p[2] = (#^3 + 3 # - 1 &);
p[3] = (5 # - 2 &);

polycompose1[indexlist_List] := Construct[Function, Collect[(Composition @@ p /@ indexlist)[#], #]]

polycompose1[indexlist0]

(* Out: 50 - 210 #1 + 225 #1^2 - 70 #1^3 + 150 #1^4 + 25 #1^6 & *)

(* Contrast with Composition @@ p /@ indexlist0,
   which gives simply (#1^2 + 1 &)@*(5 #1 - 2 &)@*(#1^3 + 3 #1 - 1 &). *)
```

I'm a bit worried about whether the unbound `Slot` could "leak" somehow, or maybe get bound by some other `Function` in some contexts before it has a chance to get bound by the `Function` in `Construct`.

Another way I have of doing this is

```
polycompose2[indexlist_List] := Block[{x}, 
 With[{body = Collect[(Composition @@ p /@ indexlist)[x], x]}, 
  Function[x, #] & @ body]]

Block[{a},
  polycompose1[indexlist0][a] === polycompose2[indexlist0][a]]

(* Out: True *)
```

This seems safer, but again, I'm not sure if one is better than the other, especially if I'm doing this many times and want to avoid unnecessary `With`s.

EDIT: Yet another way is

```
polycompose3[indexlist_List] := 
 MapAt[Evaluate, 
  Function[Collect[(Composition @@ p /@ indexlist)[#], #]], 1]

polycompose3[indexlist0] === polycompose1[indexlist0]

(* Out: True *)
```

from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/159849/63584), which I like quite a bit, and feels "safe". But is it?

So, my questions are:

- Is there anything actually "unsafe" about `polycompose1`? (Or, for that matter, either of the other two options?) It seems there might be, but I'm not sure.
- Are there any other ways to accomplish this (esp. if they're "safer" or more efficient)?

This question is primarily about the safest way to do this, and more specifically whether the first option can be realized as unsafe, not about simply finding a way to accomplish the task per se. (So, just to pre-empt it, I don't think this is a duplicate.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not `(Composition @@ p /@ indexlist)@# // Expand`?

Comment: @Somos hmm, yeah, I guess I could use that instead of `Collect[(Composition @@ p /@ indexlist)[#], #]`! but I'm more wondering about whether `#` is leaky there, and I don't think I'm composing *so* many polynomials that I'll need to worry about efficiency in `Collect`. but thanks for the suggestion, I had forgotten about `Expand`! :)